# Regarding Fourier transform of $\int_{0}^{t}f(e^{i \tau})d\tau$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Let $f\in L^1(\mathbb{T})$ where $\mathbb{T}$ is the unit circle in the complex plane. I need to calculate $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left(\int_{0}^{t}f(e^{i \tau})d\tau\right) e^{(-int)}dt$. The answer is $\frac{\hat{f}(n)}{in}$. Is my following approach correct?

$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left(\int_{0}^{t}f(e^{i \tau})d\tau\right) e^{(-int)}dt$

=$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(e^{it})\left(\int_{0}^{t} e^{(-in \tau)}d\tau\right)dt$ (if we substitute $\tau=t$)

=$\frac{\hat{f}(n)}{in}$

Comment: No, your argument is not correct. You have to integrate by parts to get the formula.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy OK with integration by parts I get $\left[\int_{0}^{t}f(e^{i \tau})d\tau\; e^{(-int)}\right]_{-\pi}^{\pi}-\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(e^{it})\int e^{(int)}dt$. Why is the first term zero?

Comment: The problem is $\int_0^{t} f(e^{is}) \, ds$ need not  be a periodic function. If it is periodic you will get the first term as $0$. Otherwise you modify the function to make it periodic.